# REST: multiple independent collections under same root

Tags: rest

I have two types of resources: `Query` and `User`.

I am `POST`ing to `/queries` to create a new query.
and `POST`ing to `/users` to create a new user.

Which path should I post to , to create a new `Query` collection and a new `User` collection ?

As per my understanding, we `POST` to a resource/collection parent , to create that resource/collection. In this case, the parent for `Users` and `Queries` would be the same, if I `POST` to the parent, how do I identify which collection should be created?

Can I use a factory path to generate these collections, if yes, how?

TL;DR - I use `/queries` and `/users` to create a `Query` and `User` **resource** respectively, what path should i use to create the `Queries` and `Users` **collection**?

EDIT: 
I am looking for advice on how this is usually achieved in REST.

Comment: You have multiple query collections, each of which has zero or more queries?

Comment: no, i have a single Query collection and a single User collection

Comment: the admin can send a list of queries to create the whole query collection. 
the admin can send a single resource to create a single query.

Comment: For simplicity, both endpoints could accept an array as request body. The users may send a full array of entities and the Admins just an array of 1 element.

Comment: @Laiv they can accept an array, i am just looking for the appropriate way in REST to do this. Also, in this case, it looks like a hack to check the array length equal to 1, everytime i need to overwrite the query collection.

Comment: Your problem is implentation detail, have nothing to do with REST. The check could be done from the client side.

Comment: @Laiv umm, as far as i know, to create a resource, we POST to its parent, in this case if i want to create a query, i POST to /queries, so the question is where should i POST to if i want to create Queries ?

I know it can be achieved through various ways, i can even have a different endpoint for that, just wanting to know how people actually do it when they create such RESTful services.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you try to achieve. You said that you still have just one collection under `/queries` and `/users`. What should be the result of sending new collection?

1. **New collection overwrites currently existing collection**

   In this case new collection effectively substitutes an existing one. In that case I would say that PUT request to `/queries` and `/users` with new collection as a payload is the way to go.
2. **Elements from new collection are appended to existing entries**

   In that case you can provide new endpoint for that, e.g. `POST /queries/bulk` with collection of queries to append.

---

If your concern is that underlying collection might not exist when POSTing new (single) element – that should not bother API user at all. `GET /queries` should be considered a list (maybe empty one), whether or not something physically exists there. Similarily, `POST /queries` should always work, and it's API implementation job to create underlying physical collection if one doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for a fairly good explanation. I am trying to follow the guidelines from here http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html. It says, POST request to parent when you want to create a resource. The whole queries collection is a resource in itself, so it wasn't clear to me if I should POST to the /queries endpoint to create Queries. 
my requirement is to create a new collection, similar to 1, but no previous collection exists.

Comment: But a collection is not a resource _per se_. I don't know if I understand correctly, but I think that you are thinking of a collection here like e.g. `List` in Java, where one needs to create new instance of the list to put elements in it. That's a total mix of concepts. For API user, the collection of queries under `/queries` always exists, but can be empty.

Comment: *“The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. **Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on**. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time.”* - Roy Fielding